# How to get the last week date from Sunday to Saturday

Tags: sql, date

I have the following table:

```
Date          Value
4/13/2014     25
4/14/2014     35
4/15/2014     30
4/16/2014     25
4/17/2014     21
4/18/2014     20
4/19/2014     42
4/20/2014     54
4/21/2014     44
4/22/2014     47
4/23/2014     48
4/24/2014     34
4/25/2014     32
4/26/2014     18
4/27/2014     20
4/28/2014     32
4/29/2014     34
```

Which updates daily.

How can I have a SQL query which adds the total `Value` from last week (Sunday-Saturday)?

In this case, the Sunday is 4/20 and Saturday is 4/26.

I currently have the following query which gets the week from this week:

```
SELECT * , DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date) AS [DAY], CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(DAY , 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE()), 110) AS DATE) AS 'WeekEnding'
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
WHERE Date >= cast(dateadd(day,1-datepart(dw, getdate()), getdate()) as date)
--SUNDAY to SATURDAY
```

Comment: Made any attempts at this yet?

Comment: I do have a query in my question which I just update that have the date from this week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to get the `SUM` of the `Value` field within the timespan of the last Sunday-Saturday. Since you said that the table is updated daily, I'll assume that you mean the last *actual* week, and not just the last week that happens to be in the DB.

Here's one query that sums the records by filtering between Sunday-Saturday. In your example data, the total is `277`.

```
SELECT SUM(Value) AS TotalValue
FROM ValueTable
WHERE Date >= DATEADD(day, -((DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) - 6,
              DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND
      Date <= DATEADD(day, -(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7,
              DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Explanation: the `DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` parts simply removes the time portion of the current datetime. The other part, `DATEADD(day, -(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7)` subtract the difference between the current date's `weekday` and Saturday, yield a date of last Saturday.

Comment: Yes, the table will keep adding data but anytime I view the table I only want data from last week and not keep adding.

Comment: So for example, if today is Tuesday the 29th, the Sunday date the query should use is 4/20 and not 4/27. Is that what it's doing?

Comment: @SiKni8: Indeed, because all it does is first pick the last Saturday in both cases (4/26) and then just subtract 6 days for Sunday (4/20).

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle you could try.  IW - week number in a year, according to ISO standard:

```
SELECT to_char( Date , 'IW' ), SUM (Value)
FROM TableA
GROUP BY to_char( Date , 'IW' );
```

Comment: Would that relate to the dates that I have? I am starting out SQL so I am not too sure...

Comment: Would be better if you provide your desired result.

Comment: Would this work: `SELECT * , DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date) AS [DAY], CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(DAY , 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE()), 110) AS DATE) AS 'WeekEnding'
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
WHERE Date >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, getdate()), -2) AND Date <= DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0,getdate()), -1))
--LAST SUNDAY to LAST SATURDAY`

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way to get data from last Saturday to Sunday is:

```
select * from my_table_name where my_date between 
DATEADD(dd, DATEPART(DW,GETDATE())*-1+1, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(dd, DATEPART(DW,GETDATE())*-1+7, GETDATE())
```

Where `DATEADD(dd, DATEPART(DW,GETDATE())*-1+1, GETDATE())` is last Saturday and
`DATEPART(DW,GETDATE())*-1+7, GETDATE())` is the coming Sunday.