# Is there a way to get a range of dates from Saturday to Sunday of the previous week (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have a SQL question. Is there a way to get a range of dates from Sunday to Saturday.

I saw individual dates were discussed before but I don't see the range of 7 days.

```
WHERE DATE BETWEEN @LastSunday AND @LastSaturday
```

If someone knows, would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the date from last Sunday to Saturday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391658/how-to-get-the-date-from-last-sunday-to-saturday)

Comment: @KenWhite thank you. I saw they used this code WHERE
    CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATE )) >= DATEADD(d, -8, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0, current_timestamp), 0)) --PREVIOUS SUNDAY
AND
    CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATE )) <= DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0, current_timestamp), 0)) --PREVIOUS SATURDAY;
I get for some reason instead of 12/26 - 01/01 I get 12/28 - 01/04...